# Getting HTML Select options from one Table and Post it to another table with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

```
<select name="Select_Category" >
    <option value="Selected"> --- Category ---</option>
    <?php
    $Result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    while($Row=mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
    $GetCategoryId=$Row['Id'];
    $GetCategoryName=$Row['Category_Name'];
    ?>
    <option value="$GetCategoryId"><?php echo $GetCategoryName; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

This is how i m getting html select values from the table category... But when i am inserting it into db in the products table the colum category_id is shwoing value =0
i need the category id of the option selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate the HTML output within the while loop - Not across separate php code snippets.

```
...
while (...) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
}
....
```

**Edit:**

```
<select name="Select_Category" >
  <option value="Selected">--- Category ---</option>
  <?php
    $Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)) {
      $GetCategoryId = $Row['Id'];
      $GetCategoryName = $Row['Category_Name'];
      echo '<option value="' . $GetCategoryId . '">' . $GetCategoryName . '</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Not working I closed the while loop but now its showing only 1 value in select option.

Comment: Updated answer to show you where the changes need to be in your code.

Comment: Thanks Man Its Working Now.. But can you please explain me what was wrong with my code ?

Comment: Your `while` loop was getting fully executed in your first `<?php ... ?>` code snippet (even though you left out the closing '}'). There is syntax for declaring while loops across separate php requests. See [php while() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).